# Doctrine query "where notIn" subquery issue

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In Symfony2, I have a many:many relationship between users and roles.
I am trying to get a list of all the users which are not linked to the `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` role.

Before migrating to Symfony2/Doctrine, I had achieved this with a simple `NOT IN` sql query, but for the life of me I can't achieve the same effect with doctrine.

Here is what I am trying:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb2 = $qb;

$dql = $qb->select('sa.id')
          ->from('AcmeAdminBundle:User', 'sa')
          ->leftJoin('sa.roles', 'r')
          ->andWhere('r.role = :role')
          ->getDQL();

$result = $qb2->select('u')
              ->from('AcmeAdminBundle:User', 'u')
              ->where($qb2->expr()->notIn('u.id', $dql))
              ->setParameter('role', 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')

$users = $result->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But this is the error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 140 near 'sa LEFT JOIN': 
Error: 'sa' is already defined.
```

And this is the output:

```
SELECT u 
FROM AcmeAdminBundle:User sa 
LEFT JOIN sa.roles r, AcmeAdminBundle:User u 
WHERE u.id NOT IN (
                   SELECT sa.id 
                   FROM AcmeAdminBundle:User sa 
                   LEFT JOIN sa.roles r 
                   WHERE r.role = :role
                  )
```

No idea why it is outputting like that as it should not be performing `LEFT JOIN` two times, my suspicion is that it has something to do with having two QueryBuilder instances, but could be something else entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `MEMBER OF` or in your case `NOT MEMBER OF` option.

```
$qb->select('sa.id')
   ->from('AcmeAdminBundle:User', 'sa')
   ->where(":Role NOT MEMBER OF sa.roles")
   ->setParameter("Role", <<ROLE_ID_OR_ROLE_ENTITY>>);
```

I didn't test this code, but it should give you some idea.

Full documentation can be found at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html